# Will the AMDGPU PRO driver for AMD R9 270X work in Ubuntu 16.04 with my AMD HD 7870?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics, gpu, gpu-driver

I have an HD 7870 and I read it is the exact same card with the R9 270X, just with another name. I want to upgrade from 14.04, but the AMDGPU PRO does not support the 7870. However, it supports the R9 290X. Will it work?